# How can I make a JS button with HTML style properties

Tags: javascript, button

I have been trying to find an UNDERSTANDABLE way of creating a JS button but I can't understand parent node child eating and whatnot. I feel so close to perfecting my little game but can't quite get there.

```
var health=100;
var ehealth=100;
var atk;
var eatk;

function attack(x){
  x=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
  atk=x;
  ehealth=ehealth-atk
  document.write('Enemy Health:' + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + ehealth + '&nbsp; &nbsp;')
}

function eattack(x){
  x=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
  eatk=x;
  health=health-eatk
  document.write('Health:' + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + health + '<br/>\n')
}

function dead(){
  if(health<=0&&ehealth<=0){
    document.write('A Draw');
  }else{
    if(health<=0){
      document.write('You Lose');
    }else{
      if(ehealth<=0){
        document.write('You Win');
      }
    }
  }
}

function battleRound() {
  attack(0);
  eattack(0);
  dead();

  if( health>=0&&ehealth>=0 ) {
    setTimeout( battleRound, 400 );
  }
}
</script>
<button onclick='battleRound()'>Start</button>
<button onclick="document.location.reload(true)">Reset</button>
</body>
```

I want the reset button to appear after the battle is complete but the whole internet appears to be screaming child node and parent something :(
4th question I've asked today so sorry for my newbie-ish-nes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a style of display: none to the reset button then show it once the battle is complete by using.

```
element.removeAttribute("style")
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding thick, what's a style?

Comment: +1 Probably what I'd do. But if you really want to create a new one, IMO use jQuery, it's much simpler than native JS

Comment: Style tag, e.g. `<input type='button' id='button1' style='display:none;' />`

Comment: I would also recommend using jQuery

Comment: How would I do this in jQuery because I've never used it before

Comment: $( '#js-reset-button' ).css( 'display', 'block' ); You need to add a id of js-reset-button to the reset button

Comment: Where do I insert the $( '#js-reset-button' ).css( 'display', 'block' ); ?

Comment: At the end of your dead function i think